# How to copy ADF pipeline to different new branch without affecting main branch?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

We have a main branch that we are using to publish to prod which contains all of the working and WIP pipelines. Now we would like to separate these WIP pipelines to a different branch, since there will be a new team working on it.
Now we tried creating a new branch that is based on our main branch. The newBranch should only have the new team's pipelines but when we try to delete the other pipelines in newBranch, the delete is considered a commit and therefore will affect the main branch if we pull.

Is there any other way we could do this? There are already hundreds of pipelines in WIP so recreating the  pipelines and datasets would take too much time.

We tried creating the newBranch, expecting that we could just delete the other pipelines that should not be accessed by the new team.

Comment: this would be easier to follow with some screenshots if you can do that w/o showing anything sensitive. Also - on this line "There are already hundreds of pipelines in WIP so recreating the pipelines and datasets would take too much time." - are you aware that you can copy the JSON? You would still need to tweak some things manually but it gets you to a pretty good starting point.